How to export a GLB animation for augmented reality?
Is there a away I can export this animation as a GLB for augmented reality?
The file setup:
I have a sheet metal part that I imported from SolidWorks as .ply, instead of rigging the sheet metal in Blender for bending the metal from its starting to ending position, I just made individual frames of the model in SolidWorks and exported each one, like frame1.ply, frame2.ply, frame3.ply, etc.
I imported all the .ply files, then just animated the viewports of each imported .ply to be on/off as needed in the animation timeline.
When I play the animation it visibly looks correct, but when I export the GLB file, there is no animation, it just exports as all of the .ply objects on top of eachother.
Thanks for your help.

A GLB file wouldn't even know what a Blender viewport was, let alone whether it's visibility is turned on or off. Here is Blender's specification for GLB export showing what it can export and this is the section on animation export.

Thanks for the info, I’ll look into this. I just removed all the viewport on/off and and instead keyframed the x,y,z transform scale of each .ply, to go from 0,0,0 (off) to 1,1,1 (on) as needed in the timeline. With interpolation mode set to Constant, but this seems to be treating the animations as 17 separate animations instead of playing them at the same time with the scaling change happening at each frame. Do I need to do some parenting hierarchy to get all animations to play simultaneously. Thanks for your help

I suspect you're going to have to rethink your workflow from scratch. All you are doing by keyframing the scale is changing how it will be viewed in Blender's own viewport wich probably won't transfer to whatever software your augmented reality uses.

I thought that since essentially each object I have imported into blender is like having multiple still characters all animated (in my case scaling from 0 to 1) simultaneously in a scene, it’s just in my case all the “characters” are just a different frame/position of the same object. Is there an easy way to export a GLB where multiple objects/characters are all doing different animations within the same 5 second loop? Thanks again

Might be worth investigatiing the NLA editor in that case but it sounded from your original description as if they were in different scenes.

Essentially the timeline keyframes are set so that object 1 (frame1.ply) is scaled 1,1,1 from frame 0 to frame 5 on the timeline, then scales to 0,0,0 on frame 6, object 2 (frame2.ply) is scaled 0,0,0 from frame 0 to frame 5, then scales to 1,1,1 on frame 6 (the same frame where object 1 scales to 0,0,0). This pattern repeats for the rest of the objects.
